# The back of my house doesn't have WiFi Signal

Tags: wireless-networking

How can I extend the signal to the back of my house? I was thinking of buying a Ethernet cable and then getting an access point to extend the wireless. If so, what are some suggestions for the wireless access points?

It's a Belkin F5D7230-4 version 2000 router.

Should I use a repeater instead? I don't know if I want to use an access point with a ethernet cable or a repeater. It would be best if it were wireless, like if it can just pick up the wireless signal and extend it further.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/45960/improve-wireless-signal has a lot of options. This question sounds very similar...

Comment: Where is the wireless router in relationship to the “center” of your house?  What model of wireless router are you using?  We might be able to recommend some changes to the router’s location/firm wear version if we can have these two pieces of information.

Comment: I'll get back to you with the router model, but it has to be in the front of the house so both us and the tenants upstairs have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a long way to go, try a pair of '[homeplugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug)' instead of a lot of cable. Home-grade Wireless Access points are all quite much-of-a-muchness now so any of the mainstream brands (Belkin, Netgear, Linksys etc.) will do - perhaps match the kit you already have? You may want to match the speed of your homeplugs with that of the AP you purchase (whether it be an 802.11g or n variant) - the common homeplug speeds are 85Mbit/Sec. 200 and 1Gbit/Sec. The first two speeds will be fine for an 802.11g (54Mbit/Sec) wireless AP, 200Mbit or 1Gbit will be better for an 802.11n AP.

Comment: I've had good success with the D-Link 85Mbps homeplugs, so I can recommend them.

Comment: What was the model? I cannot find "homeplugs" on their websites.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your wireless access points support [WDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System), you don't need a cable -- you can interconnect them wirelessly, assuming that they have better aerials than your computers so that they can talk to each other.

Comment: This sounds like what I want.

Comment: Scott Hanselman did something similar. Check out http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConfiguringTwoWirelessRoutersWithOneSSIDNetworkNameAtHomeForFreeRoaming.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Ethernet over mains.