# Extending wireless with extra router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which methods help to improve wireless signal?](https://superuser.com/questions/45960/which-methods-help-to-improve-wireless-signal)

I have a Samsung Smart tv, and it is far from the router, hence the signal is very weak.

I was hoping to give it a wired connection. Now, I have a few doubts, I have a TP-Link WR642g router that has an option to enable bridges. This is an extended range G router.

If I buy a new n150 Belkin basic router, will I be able to connect both of them so as to get a good Wi-Fi signal all over the house, or should I keep the second router near the tv and wire the TV through Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth looking into powerline networking, I use it for similar reasons and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Not all routers provide a feature like this. You need to either make sure you find a router that provides a "repeater" or "bridge" feature, or a router that is supported by a third-party firmware like DD-WRT or OpenWRT (this is a more advanced setup, though). Look through sales documentation carefully. Based on your description of the situation, I would recommend a repeater, which will introduce a bit of latency but improve reception at the TV significantly.

Comment: any idea on which brand to go for?